# Mobile menu displays submenus on top of parent. Need it to display right below on an own line

Tags: menus, mobile, responsive

I really need some assistance. Been sitting with this for hours now.

Mobile mode, need the children to show up on their own line below their parent.

Right now it looks as on desktop (which works on desktop) but not on mobile.

[image: Screenshot:]

[image: Code]

Comment: Can you add in the HTML that is generated by `wp_nav_menu`?  Also, what does your mobile navigation CSS/JS look like?

Comment: It just displays MENU and NAVIGATION , clicking on it doesnt do nothing

Comment: Not sure what you mean by HTML

Comment: You said the HTML you included in your question was manual/hard coded.  The `wp_nav_menu()` function usually outputs more code than that, so I'm wondering if you can either go to your browser and copy the code that is in the source or if you can provide a link so that we can see the site and perhaps trouble shoot it live.  The problem is most likely that you've generated CSS and JS for the manually input HTML above, but that WordPress is outputting different HTML with it's menu function.

Comment: Yeah, so Im guessing this is what you are asking about:

  <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
     'menu' => 'Main Menu', 
     'container_class' => 'mobilemenu',
     'container' => 'ul', 
     'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Walker()
     )); 
  ?>

Comment: I had to change the topic name...